# White Gap CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm having a small issue with some CSS/HTML. I'm unsure what it is. I think its me being stupid but i'm unsure...

The issue is this white line:
[image: screenshot]

CSS

```
    body{
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0;
}

.main-header nav{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url('img/menu-bg.png');
    padding: 15px 0px;
}

.main-header .logo{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 12.5px;
}

.main-header .logo a:hover{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 150%
}

.main-header ul{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 12.5px;
}
.main-header ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

.main-header nav a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 150%
}

.main-header nav a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: #FFBB00;
}

.main-header .nav-line{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    background-color: #FFBB00;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project 2</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <h2><a href="#">Project 2</a></h2>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What white line? I can't tell from the image you posted.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. You've posted a picture that implies very little about its connection with the DOM and the CSS you've attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `overflow:hidden` from the .nav-line div fixes it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Dtr5n/)**

Or add `overflow:auto;` to your nav:

```
.main-header nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background:#000;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Qg62E/)**

Either way your top container content is pushing the content below it down by about a pixel.

Answer (score 1):

The Logo is pushing the line. Its line height is too tall to fit into the parent, so, setting `.main-header .logo {line-height: 11px;}` solves it.

Note that this is not the only solution, but is the solution which points the origin of the gap. You could also solve this by setting a height on the parent and overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the img/menu-bg.png who have one line of white pixels or 60% black. 
Why you don't use background:#000; ?